# How to load fonts in a static Class and use as JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I tried to **export a game** which was **running perfectly fine** in eclipse to a **runnable jar file**. It didn't properly launch so i tried to launch it using the terminal and I recieved this error message:

```
java.io.IOException: Can't read res\fonts\slkscr.ttf
        at java.awt.Font.createFont(Unknown Source)
        at dev.tilegame.gfx.FontLoader.loadFont(FontLoader.java:12)
        at dev.tilegame.gfx.Assets.init(Assets.java:21)
        at dev.tilegame.Game.init(Game.java:55)
        at dev.tilegame.Game.run(Game.java:93)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I use an **Assets** class to store all my assets:

```
public static void init() {
    font28 = FontLoader.loadFont("res/fonts/slkscr.ttf", 28);
    font52 = FontLoader.loadFont("res/fonts/slkscr.ttf", 52);
```

And thats the **FontLoader**:

```
public class FontLoader {

public static  Font loadFont(String path, float size){
    try {
        return Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(path)).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, size);
    } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

-Thanks

edit:

EntityManager:

```
public class EntityManager {

private Handler handler;
private Player player;
private ArrayList<Entity> entities;
private ArrayList<Entity> postentities;
Iterator<Entity> it;
private Comparator<Entity> renderSorter = new Comparator<Entity>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entity a, Entity b) {
        if (a.getY() + a.getHeight() < b.getY() + b.getHeight())
            return -1;
        return 1;
    }
};

public EntityManager(Handler handler, Player player) {
    this.handler = handler;
    this.player = player;
    entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    postentities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    addEntity(player);
}

public void tick() {
    Iterator<Entity> it = entities.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Entity e = it.next();
        e.tick();
        if (!e.isActive())
            it.remove();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < postentities.size(); i++) {
        entities.add(postentities.get(i));
        postentities.remove(i);
    }

    entities.sort(renderSorter);
}

public void render(Graphics g) {
    for (Entity e : entities) {
        e.render(g);
    }
    player.postRender(g);
}

public void addEntity(Entity e) {
    entities.add(e);
}

public void postaddEntity(Entity e) {
    postentities.add(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're having is that when you have a path to a file within a JAR, it is a **opaque URL**. This means it does not represent an actual file, rather it represents a path within a compressed JAR. In your case, you should use `getResourceAsStream` to get an `InputStream` to the correct file:

```
public static Font loadFont(String path, float size){
    try {
        Font f = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, FontLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
        return f.deriveFont(size);
    } catch (FontFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note that **the path should begin with a leading slash**; this represents the root of the jar file. (E.g. `"res/fonts/slkscr.ttf"` becomes `"/res/fonts/slkscr.ttf"`)

Comment: This is the error message that came now.

Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics$MetricsKey.init(Unknown Source)
 at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(Unknown Source)
 at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.getFontMetrics(Unknown Source)
 at dev.tilegame.gfx.Text.drawString(Text.java:16)
 at dev.tilegame.inventory.Inventory.render(Inventory.java:75)
 at dev.tilegame.entities.creatures.Player.postRender(Player.java:228)
 at dev.tilegame.entities.EntityManager.render(EntityManager.java:57)

Comment: Can I see EntityManager.java?

Comment: Sorry, and Text.java? You don't have to edit it into your question; you could use a [gist](https://gist.github.com)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Andi9904/64deea83669531cfe8ad4e21fba73f50

And thats the error message that pops up when I launch the game in eclpise now: 
https://gist.github.com/Andi9904/8625deb12c3845401174b6b9ffdac3cb

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`return Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(path)).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, size);`

You can use

`Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream(new File(path))).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN,size);`

The FileINputStream will input the file for you

Check this out for more about FileINputStream:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html

Comment: Now it throws a NullPointer. So whats the path which I should enter?

font28 = FontLoader.loadFont("res/fonts/slkscr.ttf", 28);
this is the current Path